# Script which subtract two file sizes

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to subtract sizes of two files. I found location of that files and then I used command:

```
du -h /bin/ip | cut -d "K" -f1
```

I got 508 and I wanted to create variable

```
x=$((du -h /bin/ip | cut -d "K" -f1))
```

but at the result I got

> "-bash: du -h /bin/ip | cut -d 'K' -f1: division by 0 (error token is "bin/ip | cut -d 'K' -f1")"

What did I do wrong? How can i put this value in variable?

Comment: Replace `$((...))` with `$(...)`. Alternatively `($(...))` to create an array.

Comment: Btw., what if /bin/ip grows a bit or two...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What did I do wrong?

You used [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) `$(( ... ))` instead of a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) `$( ... )`. As a result shell interpreted `/bin` as `/` as division and `bin` as `0` (because there is no variable named `bin`) and tried to divide by 0.

> How can i put this value in variable?

Use a command substitution:

```
x=$(du -h /bin/ip | cut -d "K" -f1)
```

But it would be way more reliable to use [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) for collecting information about files:

```
x=$(stat -c %s /bin/ip)
```

To substract two file sizes, you can again use command substitutions to get the size, but use arithmetic expansion to calculate the difference.

```
difference=$(( $(stat -c %s file1) - $(stat -c %s file2) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -le 'print((-s "file1.txt") - (-s "file2.txt"))'
```

- `-l` adds newline to `print`
- `-s` returns a file size (see [-x](http://p3rl.org/-x))